# LINQ on EF6: Is there difference in terms of performance between query syntax and method calls?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Which syntax results in better performance?

```
var vRec = (bNoTracking ? tblOrders.AsNoTracking() : tblOrders);
return vRec
     .Where(x => (x.WarehouseId == iWarehouseId) && (x.OrderId == iOrderId))
     .FirstOrDefault<tblOrder>();
```

OR

```
var vRec = (bNoTracking ? tblOrders.AsNoTracking() : tblOrders);
return (from rec in vRec
        where (rec.WarehouseId == iWarehouseId) && (rec.OrderId == iOrderId)
        select rec)
       .FirstOrDefault<tblOrder>();
```

This question is for EF-6 (for SQL Express 2014) and EF-7 version 7.0.0-rc1-final (for SQLite).

Note: I'm not looking for opinions on coding style difference, only whether there is technical reason to prefer one another.

Comment: Inspect the SQL generated for it. Though I would imagine the result is identical.

Comment: What 'difference' is there? And how does it relate between the EF versions?

Comment: Get out your stopwatch and time it?

Comment: I used my stopwatch, and they are pretty much the same, but I only have few records. My concern is when I have hundreds of thousands of records. @Grant, I didn't know you can do that. THANK YOU!

Comment: I can confirm that both queries return [exactly the same SQL.](http://i.imgur.com/vBaGqXB.png)

Comment: @ScottKaye and Rob please post your answer and I will marked it as answered :)

Comment: Glad I could help, though Rob definitely beat me by 30 minutes - if he posts an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @ScottKaye MSDN beat you by some sizable margin anyway :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Haha, I won't be winning any awards for cleverness, I just thought the generated SQL might be useful to OP.

Comment: `public static class DbSetExtensions { public static IDbSet WithNoTrackingOf(this IDbSet dbSet, bool noTrackingFlag) => noTrackingFlag ? dbSet.AsNoTracking() : dbSet; }` then `return vRec.WithNoTrackingOf(bNoTracking).FirstOrDefault(x => x.WarehouseId == iWarehouseId && x.OrderId = iOrderId);`. And PLEASE Stop using Hungarian notation. Please. It's 2016 for crying out loud, not 1996!

Comment: @ErikE, Great idea! But I got this error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<TEntity>'**. Any idea?

Comment: It just took some fiddling: `public static IQueryable<T> WithNoTrackingOf<T>(this IDbSet<T> dbSet, bool noTrackingFlag) where T : class => noTrackingFlag ? dbSet.AsNoTracking() : dbSet;`

Comment: @ErikE you are a champion!!! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both queries will be converted to the same SQL, meaning performance will be identical.  It just depends on if you prefer the "fluent" syntax (`.Where()`) or LINQ query expressions (`where`).

The SQL generated from my test MSSQL database is as follows, revealed with LINQPad:

[image]

This looks to be about as optimized as it'll get, so I'd say no further tweaking is necessary unless you're running this select in some kind of loop.

Comment: More specifically - query syntax is converted to method syntax which then in turn converted to SQL (or whatever query language/constructs provider uses) - [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)